# Apache Beam configuration from environment variables

Tags: java, apache-beam

I was surprised to find that there doesn't seem to be a way to pull Beam configuration from Environment Variables (for the direct runner). In case it helps anyone, I've create the code snippet below as an answer - but I was wondering if there was a better (or more official) variant? This definitely feels hacky...

Answer (score 0):

```java
    private static String[] AddArgsFromEnvironmentVariables(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<String> argsWithEnvVariables = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(args));
        Map<String, String> env = System.getenv();
        for (String envName : env.keySet()) {
            if (envName.startsWith("BEAM_")) {
                String argName = envName.substring(5);
                argsWithEnvVariables.add(0, "--" + argName + "=" + env.get(envName));
            }
        }
        return argsWithEnvVariables.toArray(args);
    }
```

How to use:

```java
PipelineOptionsFactory.fromArgs(AddArgsFromEnvironmentVariables(args))
```